# HighCharts : Total Value is not showing in Pie Chart

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

I am Trying to Display The Total Users on the PieChart. But my "getting the Total Code" is not Working. It Displays Nothing.

Here is The Code that I am Using :

```
events: {
        load: function(event) {
          var total = 0;
            for(var i=0, len=this.series[0].yData.length; i<len; i++){
                total += this.series[0].yData[i];
            }
          var text = this.renderer.text(
            'Total: ' + total,
            this.plotLeft,
            this.plotTop - 20
        ).attr({
            zIndex: 5
        }).add()
        }
          }
```

If I Can Show You My Full Code Here it is :

```
var data = <?php echo $data ; ?>

data.forEach(function(el) {
el.name = el.label;
el.y = Number(el.value);
});

Highcharts.chart('pieDiv', {
chart: {

    plotBackgroundColor: null,
    plotBorderWidth: null,
    plotShadow: false,
    type: 'pie',
    events: {
        load: function(event) {
          var total = 0;
            for(var i=0, len=this.series[0].yData.length; i<len; i++){
                total += this.series[0].yData[i];
            }
          var text = this.renderer.text(
            'Total: ' + total,
            this.plotLeft,
            this.plotTop - 20
        ).attr({
            zIndex: 5
        }).add()
        }
          }
},
title: {
    text: undefined
},
credits: {
  enabled: false
},
exporting: { enabled: false } ,
tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b> ({point.y} 
Users)'
},
plotOptions: {
    pie: {
colors: 
Highcharts.map(["#59deed","#e86e65","#de8f14","#589bcf","#a05195","#35cc95", 
"#72a7b3"], function (color) {
    return {
        radialGradient: {
            cx: 0.5,
            cy: 0.3,
            r: 0.7
        },
        stops: [
            [0, color],
            [1, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(-0.3).get('rgb')] // darken
        ]
    };
 }),
         states: {
        inactive: {
            opacity: 1
        }
    },
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        fillOpacity: 1,
         showInLegend: true,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} % <br/> 
({point.y} Users)',
             style: {
                color: (Highcharts.theme && 
Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
            }
        }

    }
},
series: [{
    name: 'Users',
    colorByPoint: true,
    data: data
}]
});
```

I am Able to Get the Data on the Pie Chart . but the Total is not being Displayed. It was supposed to be appear on the top Left Corner of the Box

Comment: I think this line: var data = <?php echo data ; ?> may be a problem. In PHP you need $ before variables, right now you are trying to reach nothing basically (surprised you do not get errors). It should be $data in that line if you have some value set to that variable.
Small hint: before you set value from PHP into JS, initialize var data = '' and then data = <?php echo $data; ?>. Also, I would recommend: 
data = <?php echo $data ? $data : ''; ?>
Hope that solves the problem.

Comment: its fine. its in php file . and its working. I just edited that part on the question for my purpose. I need to know about the Code That is responsible for displaying the Total Data in The Chart Box. Which I Mentioned Separately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made a simple mistake in js for loop code using `,` instead of `;`. Check the code and working demo with total data rendered properly.

**Code:**

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      load: function() {
        var total = 0,
          len = this.series[0].yData.length,
          text;

        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
          total += this.series[0].yData[i];
        }

        text = this.renderer.text(
          'Total: ' + total,
          this.plotLeft,
          this.plotTop - 20
        ).attr({
          zIndex: 5
        }).add();
      }
    }
  }
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/o4bx6139/1/

Comment: I am not able to understand why its not working for me .? I tried your code but still nothing

Comment: Perhaps it is beneath other elements? Try to change the x and y values and check if the element is rendered at all. Also, you can try to invoke `toFront()` method on text svg element (more about it here: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#toFront).

Comment: I need the code for pie Chart. Yor example is good, but its for Line Chart

Comment: The renderer works the same in line and pie series types. Check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qau0nLz5/

Comment: You were right. my text was hidden behing the div. That's why I wasn't able to see it. although Your code helps too.

Comment: Great to hear that;)